# Can Eclipse use Maven to Download Jars without the Project being a Maven Project?

Tags: eclipse, maven, intellij-idea, eclipse-plugin, dependencies

In the IntelliJ IDE there is a way to download jars from a maven repository without a project being required to be a maven project. Is there anything like this for the Eclipse IDE?

Comment: I am pretty sure there is no such way

Comment: @Vinay - well aren't you a gloomy gus